# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) help me

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Can someone help me? I've tried searching for a few ways to fix it, but no success!

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Answer (score 7):

To solve this issue you need to stop mysql process either through:

```
systemctl stop mysql
```

or

```
service mysql stop
```

after than you’ll need to expose the directory which has the socket configurations to the user who is running the process, this can happen through:

```
sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql
```

then go back and start / restart mysql process again through:

```
systemctl start mysql
```

or

```
service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case not install mariadb server, You can try here

```
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error during the process to install mariadb (exemple) :

```
Enter current password for root (enter for none):
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

You have to start mariadb in the first place :

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

Or if you are using WSL :

```
service start mariadb
```